# Kafka Stream 2.3 DeserializationExceptionHandler

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Error: Inside Custom DeserializationExceptionHandler in Kafka Stream DSL

1.While accessing Processor context inside custom Deserialization Exception handler. For Some Poison Pills ->Error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: This should not happen as partition() should only be called while a record is processed.

(As if this context object is shared?) AND Sometimes the Header information inside Processor context is from previous messages(Thread leak).

And while restarting the Kafka Stream ,some of these poison pills are consumed again.

Note:My response is always to continue in overriden handle method.

Could anyone explain this unusual behavior?Is it a bug in Kafka 2.3 DSL?

Any Suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: Please add the code sample.

Comment: If offsets are not committed -- what would happen for the case you describe as Kafka Stream crashes -- or restart the processing would continue where it left off and thus you get stuck. -- As @asolanki mentione, can you share the handler code?